# How do I remove this numbers from text?

Tags: php, regex, string

```
Ð½Ð°Ð½Ð¸1,ÑÐ¿Ð°Ð»Ð½Ð¸1
è§†é¢‘3,æ•™ç¨‹3,
ÐºÐ½Ð¸Ð³Ð¸3,ÑÐºÐ°Ñ‡Ð°Ñ 5‚web2.0
```

above is forieng form of foreign languages which is stored in MySQL. I want to remove 
numbers from above all lines. say `1 , 3 , 5` etc. and I want to keep `web2.0`

note:- there are about 300k lines. above is just a sample.

```
preg_replace('/(\w)\d+$/m', '$1', $tags);
```

the above one is an option for almost all cases but this fails in above case...

Comment: Use `str_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php or `preg_replace` and match for numbers `[0-9]`

Comment: You want to keep numbers proceeded for a word character?

Comment: the result must be ÐºÐ½Ð¸Ð³Ð¸,ÑÐºÐ°Ñ‡Ð°Ñ ‚web2.0. this is for last line I am talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'Ð½Ð°Ð½Ð¸1,ÑÐ¿Ð°Ð»Ð½Ð¸1
è§†é¢‘3,æ•™ç¨‹3,
ÐºÐ½Ð¸Ð³Ð¸3,ÑÐºÐ°Ñ‡Ð°Ñ 5‚
';

$str = preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $str);

var_dump($str);
```

#### Output

```
string(122) "Ð½Ð°Ð½Ð¸,ÑÐ¿Ð°Ð»Ð½Ð¸
è§†é¢‘,æ•™ç¨‹,
ÐºÐ½Ð¸Ð³Ð¸,ÑÐºÐ°Ñ‡Ð°Ñ ‚
"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/AA4kQ4f0).

### Update

```
<?php

$str = 'Ð½Ð°Ð½Ð¸1,ÑÐ¿Ð°Ð»Ð½Ð¸1
è§†é¢‘3,æ•™ç¨‹3,
ÐºÐ½Ð¸Ð³Ð¸3,ÑÐºÐ°Ñ‡Ð°Ñ 5‚web2.0

';

$str = preg_replace('/(?<!\w|\.)\d+/', '', $str);

var_dump($str);
```

#### Output

```
string(130) "Ð½Ð°Ð½Ð¸,ÑÐ¿Ð°Ð»Ð½Ð¸
è§†é¢‘,æ•™ç¨‹,
ÐºÐ½Ð¸Ð³Ð¸,ÑÐºÐ°Ñ‡Ð°Ñ ‚web2.0

"
```

I am not sure *exactly* your exclusions, but this won't match any number proceeded by a word character (`\w`) or by a period (`\.`).

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/01rfroA6).

Comment: but this removes web2.0 which is also included in other tags

Comment: @aron n Please edit your question to elaborate on what you don't want to match.

Comment: thanks man it seems working...one question..will it affect or trim any of these characters??

Comment: @aron n It won't trim anything besides because the negative lookbehind is non capturing.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this question with php I assume you mean something like this:

```
<?php
    $string = preg_replace ('/[0-9]+/', '', $string);
?>
```

Comment: this will eliminate all possibilities like numbers from tags. say web2.0 is in many places so it will remove 2

Comment: @aron n: you said nothing about any exceptions. Give significant details **before** people started to answer, not after.

Comment: sorry I forgot that..actually working into all these stuffs..so